# Is there a way to slow down the hover effect?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover

Is there a way to slow down a hover effect? I have a hover effect on my site (removed) that displays text on hover of the images. I want to slow down the effect by a little. It's a tad jarring how quickly the picture switches over.

How would I do that?

Comment: is an option for you to use jQuery?

Comment: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could add css3 transitions:

```
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
-ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
-o-transition: all 500ms ease;
transition: all 500ms ease;
```

Answer (score 6):

It depends on how you're displaying the text. If you're changing a CSS property you can do this with [CSS3 transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp). Below is an example.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="A"></div><div id="B"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    -moz-transition: opacity 4s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: opacity 4s; /* Opera */
    transition: opacity 4s;
}
#A {
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}
#B {
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
#B:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nwmbm/2/)**

**Edit:** David Thomas has told me that you cannot change the display with transitions. I have updated the above to use opacity.

Comment: You can't 'transition' between `display` states; certainly not between `display: block` and `display: none`. The content will simply jump, and then, perhaps, animate.

Comment: @DavidThomas, thanks for the heads up. I didn't know that. Perhaps it can be done with opacity? I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, you can transition `opacity`. I find that a better option here.

Comment: `opacity` and `height` (and other properties with specified values, basically not `auto`) can certainly transition smoothly.

Comment: Transition  (the non prefixed) should always be last

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite a bit late but look into CSS3 animations. I use an animation on one of my Garry's Mod loading screens.

```css
/* Styles go here */

button {
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-right: 50%;
}
button:hover {
  -webkit-animation: breathing 5s ease-out infinite normal;
  animation: breathing 5s ease-out infinite normal;
}
@-webkit-keyframes breathing {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes breathing {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <p>Below I have a button that changes size on mouse hover useing CSS3</p>
  <button>Hover over me!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I know it's not quite the result your looking for but I'm sure you and others can find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like, you could use jQuery .fadeIn() http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

> **.fadeIn( [duration] [, callback] )**
>   **duration** string or number determining how long the animation will run.
>   **callback** function to call once the animation is complete.